# Flutter dropChild of RenderBox not working as expected

Tags: flutter, renderbox

I want to drop/delete a Renderbox in my class

```
class RenderDynamicTimeline extends RenderBox
    with
        ContainerRenderObjectMixin<RenderBox, DynamicTimelineParentData>,
        RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin<RenderBox, DynamicTimelineParentData> {
///default Code
}
```

Here is my code for using `dropChild()`:

```
  void deleteChildBykey(Key? childKey) {
    // Find the child with the matching key
    for (final child in getChildrenAsList()) {
      final dynamicTimelineParentData = child.parentData as DynamicTimelineParentData;
      if (dynamicTimelineParentData.key == childKey) {

        dynamicTimelineParentData.previousSibling = null;
        dynamicTimelineParentData.nextSibling = null;
        
        dropChild(child);
        
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Problem is, that I get a `Null check operator used on a null value error` in the layout function from `RenderDynamicTimeline` as I see through debugging, the child is already in the RenderDynamicTimeline as child there, but the `parentData` is deleted.
The child is marked with `NEEDS-PAINT DETACHED`

How can I delete the child complete from the `RenderDynamicTimeline` class?

Comment: you mix your `RenderBox` with `ContainerRenderObjectMixin` so maybe try to call it's `remove()` method

Answer (score 1):

as @pskink mentioned, `remove` is the solution:

```
  void deleteChildBykey(Key? childKey) {
    // Find the child with the matching key
    for (final child in getChildrenAsList()) {
      final dynamicTimelineParentData = child.parentData as DynamicTimelineParentData;
      if (dynamicTimelineParentData.key == childKey) {
        remove(child);

        break;
      }
    }
  }
```